# Is it possible to set the margin height for individual pages in Pages word processor?

Tags: pdf, pages

I exported a PDF for a 2-page document I've finished typing. There's an ugly gap in the PDF where page 1 meets page 2. This is caused by the bottom margin of page 1 and the top margin of page 2.

How do I set the margins for each of theses pages separately? Currently, I'm only able to set the margin height for the overall document.

Comment: Presumably you never want to actually print this, you just intend to read it as a continuous scroll? [otherwise it will look terrible to anyone who views per page or prints it]

Comment: I guess I'm nit-picking. The problem is, it's a 2 page CV/resume and looks great in Pages. The separation between the pages that the Pages word processor adds, makes it look nice. However, when it's exported as a PDF, the document is shown as one long page. There's a big space where the first page's bottom margin and the second page's top margin meet. It's really irking me, but probably won't bother recruiters and employers. I figured I'd just adjust the margins on each page separately to eradicate the space that shows up. @Tetsujin

Comment: "shown as one long page" That's a preference in whatever you are using to read it. You cannot assume anyone else uses the same pref. Make your document to look good when printed, let your recipient figure out how they like to read. Don't try to anticipate someone else's preference. [BTW, you **can** do this, I'm just really trying to persuade you NOT to ;) It will not look good.

Comment: I've decided not to do it for the reasons you mentioned. I added the page number in the bottom margins instead. @Tetsujin

Comment: I'm very glad I persuaded you ;))) Imagine one company you submit to, gets the secretary to print out all the CVs submitted, as double-sided… & yours hits the very bottom of page one, then when they turn over & page 2 starts right at the very top…? if you were going for a graphic design job, you'd already be in the discard pile, any other job you could only hope they assumed Word failed ...which is why you used Pages in the first place, to get a jump on the guys who wrote theirs in Word, right??